# How can I organize my CSV file in R

Tags: r, excel-formula

I got .csv file with 53000 rows as follows:

```
s 
1
2
3
m
4
5
6
7
r
8
9
10
11
```

I would like to make it following format using R or excel:

```
s 1 2 3 
m 4 5 6 7 
r 8 9 10 11
```

Comment: Have you had words with your data provider? That's crazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the new row names are always alpha numeric and the values in the rows are always numeric, this reformats it into a data frame you may be looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(x = c("s", 1:3, "m", 4:7, "r", 8:11),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(var_id = cumsum(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x))) %>%
  group_by(var_id) %>%
  mutate(row_name = x[1]) %>%
  filter(!grepl("[[:alpha:]]", x)) %>%
  mutate(var_index = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-var_id) %>%
  spread(var_index, x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Three alternative implementations using `base R` and `data.table`:

**1:** with base R

```
df$id <- cumsum(grepl("\\D", df$x))
df$name <- ave(df$x, df$id, FUN = function(x) rep(x[1],length(x)))
df <- df[!grepl("\\D", df$x),]
df$pos <- ave(df$x, df$name, FUN = function(x) paste0("p",1:length(x)))

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, name ~ pos, value.var = "x")
```

this gives:

```
  name p1 p2 p3   p4
1    m  4  5  6    7
2    r  8  9 10   11
3    s  1  2  3 <NA>
```

**2:** first approach with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[, id := cumsum(grepl("\\D", x))
                ][, `:=` (name = x[1], pos = 0:(.N-1)), id
                  ][!grepl("\\D", x), .(name, x, pos=paste0("p",pos))], 
      name ~ pos, value.var = "x")
```

**3:** second approach with `data.table`, but now with the just introduced `rowid` function from the development version ([installation instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)):

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.7+
dcast(setDT(df)[, id := cumsum(grepl("\\D", x))
                ][, name := x[1], id
                  ][!grepl("\\D", x), .(name, x)], 
      name ~ rowid(name, prefix="p"), value.var = "x")
```

both `data.table` approaches result in:

```
   name p1 p2 p3 p4
1:    m  4  5  6  7
2:    r  8  9 10 11
3:    s  1  2  3 NA
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("s", 1:3, "m", 4:7, "r", 8:11), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```